# SQL to find unique id's

Tags: sql, window-functions

I want to find the count of active unique id's in a specific date range

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_tmp
(
    id integer,
    start_dt date,
    end_dt date,
    status varchar(8)
);

INSERT INTO tbl_tmp VALUES (30, '2015-11-22','2015-11-22', 'Active');
INSERT INTO tbl_tmp VALUES (30, '2015-11-23', '2015-12-06', 'Active');
INSERT INTO tbl_tmp VALUES (40, '2015-11-26', '2015-11-26', 'Active');
INSERT INTO tbl_tmp VALUES (40, '2015-11-27', '2016-02-23', 'Active');
INSERT INTO tbl_tmp VALUES (30, '2015-12-06', '2015-12-07', 'Inactive');
INSERT INTO tbl_tmp VALUES (40, '2016-02-24', '2016-08-04', 'Active');
```

Expected output:

if where clause is on start date >= '2015-11-22' and end_date <= '2015-12-05' the count of unique id's should be 2 since both 30 and 40 are active in that time range

if where clause is on start date >= '2015-11-22' and end_date <= '2015-12-10' the count of unique id's should be 1 because 30 is inactive starting '2018-12-07'

Comment: In your second case of expected output, I don't see any date with year 2018. Anything ?

Comment: Redshift and Oracle are two **very** different database products. Which one are you really using? Please add only one tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the records complete tile the time periods, we can count all actives during any time during the range and subtract any that are inactive:

```
select (count(distinct (case when 
                             then t.id
                        end)
                       )
              ) -
        count(distinct (case when t.end_dt >= r.range_start and
                                  t.start_dt <= r.range_end and
                                   t.status = 'Inactive'
                             then t.id
                        end)
              )
      ) as num_active_for_entire_range        
from tbl_temp t cross join
     (select date '2015-11-22' as range_start, date '2015-12-05' as range_end from dual
     ) r;
```

H

Actually, this is simpler if the filtering is done once:

```
select (count(distinct t.id) -
        count(distinct (case when t.status = 'Inactive'
                             then t.id
                        end)
                       )
              )
      ) as num_active_for_entire_range        
from tbl_temp t cross join
     (select date '2015-11-22' as range_start, date '2015-12-05' as range_end
     ) r
where t.end_dt >= r.range_start and
      t.start_dt <= r.range_end
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=167b266155ee6aed15839de06198725b) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are more inclined towards end date as 30 is active from 22 to 06 but still you want its status as inactive as it is inactive (in case 2 ) from 06 to 07. So latest status of the id is what you are much interested in.

You can try following query:

```
Select t.* -- or count(1) for fetching just count
(Select t.* , 
       row_number() 
        over (partition by id order by start_dt desc) as rn
from  your_table t
Where <date_conditions>) t
Where t.status = 'Active' and t.rn = 1;
```

Cheers!!